# How do I put a line under a button when its selected?

Tags: css, html, angular

I have 3 buttons:

```
<div>
  <!-- 1st button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="setState(0)"
          class="md-primary">Button 1
  </button>

  <!-- 2nd button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="setState(1)"
          class="md-primary">Button 2
  </button>

  <!-- 3rd button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="setState(2)"
          class="md-primary">Button 3
  </button>
</div>
```

this just present me three buttons, and im doing actions based on the click.

now I want to indicate which button is currently clicked so I wanted to add underline for the button, how can I do that?

it should be visible untill a new button was clicked and then the line should be moved to the newely clicked button

thanks

Comment: How long should the line be visible? A click only has a duration of about 0.001 seconds.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it should be visible untill a new button was clicked and then the line should be moved to the newelty clicked button

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <!-- 1st button -->
  <button md-button [style.border-bottom]="state === 0 ? 'solid 3px red' : ''"
          (click)="setState(0)"
          class="md-primary">Button 1
  </button>

  <!-- 2nd button -->
  <button md-button [style.border-bottom]="state === 1 ? 'solid 3px red' : ''"
          (click)="setState(1)"
          class="md-primary">Button 2
  </button>

  <!-- 3rd button -->
  <button md-button [style.border-bottom]="state === 2 ? 'solid 3px red' : ''"
          (click)="setState(2)"
          class="md-primary">Button 3
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe outline should be used here instead border to avoid jumpy buttons and use a familiar look :), just an idea ...

Comment: @GCyrillus I didn't really expect this to be the desired solution. I merely hoped this answer would motivate Jack to provide more details about what he wants exactly.

Comment: Your code doesn't provide enough information. I just assumed there is some `state` property but I can't know from the information you provided. There is no way for me to see what `setState(x)` is doing.

Comment: setState is just a method that help my component.ts to descide which list to assign to my listToDisplay property.

Comment: If `setState()` sets some state you can use that state to decide what button should be underlined. If it doesn't you need to introduce such a state.

Comment: Just add a property to your controller class called selectedState of type integer and every time you call setState update that property (from the argument that you received), and whoala!